# OpenCV VideoCapture on Large files looping back to the start frame after 4000+ frames

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, video-capture

```
import matplotlib.pyploy as plt
import cv2
def getFrame(cap):
    frameRate = 25
    frameId = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        return None
    print frameId
    if frameId < 0:
        return None
    if not (frameId % int(frameRate)):
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frameId + frameRate)
        return frame
    return None

videoFile = 'filename.webm'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFile,cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)

image = getFrame(cap)
plt.imshow(image)

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,4000.0)
image = getFrame(cap)
while(image is not None):
    plt.imshow(image)
    image = getFrame(cap)
cap.release()
```

I'm running the above code in a while loop and displaying the image. It seems that after around 4250 frames, the frame returned will be the same as the frame at the start. This loop continue after another 4250 frames.

The file I'm reading is mp4 and webm file. The behavior is the same for both types of file. videoCapture is using FFMPEG backend. Opencv version = 3.4.1, python 2.7 .

Another notable behaviour is the reading of the frame slows down as the frame increases and then went back to fast again after 4250 frames.

Edit: 
I edited the code. I think you can try running this with mp4/webm file longer than 5 minutes. I can't upload the video due to privacy reason because it is recorded in office.

When I modified the code with only cap.read(), the error disappears. I suspect this is something to do with cap.set()

Comment: Please upgrade your code to a [mcve].

Comment: I edited the code. It seems that after experimenting with multiple read() instead of set, I am able to read pass 4250 frames. Have you encountered any issues with the cv2 cap.set() method?

Answer (score 0):

Use cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 25) instead of skipping frames and setting the frame number in code.

Your code does not check the size of the video before setting cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frameId + frameRate.

You can check the size in frames with cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT).

Comment: Setting the frames doesn't seem to do anything in the video case. Every read() call still ends up reading the frame right after it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getNextFrame(cap):
    frameRate = 25
    for i in range(frameRate-1):
        cap.grab()
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    return ret, frame
```

I've found a workaround. I use grab() for the 24 frames to be skipped and then only read() for the frame I need.

I'm not sure if this is the best approach but I'll put it out here. I'll still be accepting other answers.